# Show Sqlite results to a ListView in a ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I new in android and I have just created an sqlite database ! I add values in it (hope so) and I want to show these values in a ListView.

Now in more details ... I have a ViewPager and in first fragment I have a button which fires an the setmethod of my sqlite database . In the second fragment of ViewPager I want to have a ListView ,in which the results of the Sqlite will be showed after I press a button . The problem is that even though I have created the Listview it doesn't show in my fragment . Also when I'm running my code in my device the app crashes and returns the error that I post below. I'll be grateful if someone could help me to implement tha ListView correctly and make it work !

OnCreateView :

```
public class PeopleManager extends ListFragment {

    private PeopleHelper getHelper;


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_people_manager,null);

     getHelper = new PeopleHelper(getActivity());
     ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

      List<PeopleModel> values = new ArrayList<PeopleModel>();
     ArrayAdapter<PeopleModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PeopleModel>(getActivity(),
            android.R.id.list, values);
         setListAdapter(adapter);

     return v;
 }
```

my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/peopleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="People List" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat :

```
03-02 17:37:10.449: E/AndroidRuntime(5555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to fix the exception: Replace

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

with

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

in your layout XML. The id must be from `android.R`, not your app's `R`.

After that, fix the code here:

```
 ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Change to `android.R.id.list`.

```
 ArrayAdapter<PeopleModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<PeopleModel>(getActivity(),
        android.R.id.list, values);
```

`ArrayAdapter` constructor requires a `layout` resource id for each list row. Passing in `android.R.id.list` won't work - it's not even a `layout` identifier.

After that consider adding some data to the `ArrayList` you pass to the adapter.

Comment: I have done it ! Error disappeared but nothing appears in my ListView !